# Google Sheets Query - Merging 2 queries or getting a new grantotal column for pivot result

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Image Screenshot]

Hi all!
As you can see in the picture (Table-Desired result) I am trying to get a subtotal as column for a query from the table (Main Data Source).
I have tried to merge 2 different queries in 1 cell formula without any success.
Below I show you how I wrote the formula separatedly:

1st

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("source";"'Sheet'!A:D");"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col4) group by Col1")
```

2nd

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("source";"'Foglio24'!A:D");"select Col1, sum(Col4) group by Col1 pivot Col3")
```

OR you have any suggestions by not doing 2 query merge?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
={{"Date";BYROW(UNIQUE(A3:A11),LAMBDA(x,x))},
{"Sum Qty";BYROW(UNIQUE(A3:A11),LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(B3:B11,A3:A11,x)))},
{"New";BYROW(UNIQUE(A3:A11),LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(D3:D11,A3:A11,x,C3:C11,"New")))},
{"Old";BYROW(UNIQUE(A3:A11),LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(D3:D11,A3:A11,x,C3:C11,"Old")))},
{"Sub Total";BYROW(UNIQUE(A3:A11),LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(D3:D11,A3:A11,x)))}}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we refer to this as pivoting, or is there a other complex term?

Comment: As OP expecting more than one column to act as pivot so can't achieve it directly using single query function. We must apply few tricks to make it pivot.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join them side by side using [array literals](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) `{\}` and lookup only the needed columns with `HLOOKUP`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LAMBDA(rg;
    HLOOKUP(
      {1\2\5\6\3};
      {
        SEQUENCE(1;6);
          {
            QUERY(rg;"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col4) group by Col1";0)\
            QUERY(rg;"select Col1, sum(Col4) group by Col1 pivot Col3";0)
          }
      };
      SEQUENCE(ROWS(rg);1;2);
      0
    )
  )(QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE("source";"'Sheet'!A:D");
    "where Col1 is not null";0)
  )
)
```

Add `IFERROR()`, if needed.